# Callback when a property is added to an object in Dart

Tags: dart, scripting-language

I'm currently evaluating Dart as an embedded scripting language. Our current Lua setup allows us to react on newly added or changed properties via metamethods, which we need for dynamic reloading. Is there something similar for the Dart language? The reflection API doesn't seem to offer this feature.

Comment: In Dart properties can't be added dynamically.

Comment: I didn't even notice because we only need that feature for dynamic reloading. Putting Dart of my list. Thanks for the quick reply!

Comment: You might be able to accomplish what you want with `noSuchMethod`